# Microsoft Azure Devops 2019 does not remove the build lock after stop retaining the build

Tags: devops, azure-devops-server-2019

In Azure devops 2019 I retained my old builds. Later I stopped Retaining the build however. When I click on 3 dots beside the build I do see **Retain build** again which confirms that I already stopped retaining. However I am still seeing a lock beside the build.
Is this a bug in Devops? Are these builds going to be deleted after 30 days? I do not want them.

see below image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your build is supposed retained by a release. Please check whether you have a release linked this build for CD. If you want to unlock the build, you need to remove the release associated with the build.

Find the release definition that retain the build, and then uncheck the `Retain associated artifacts`, you'll see the build will be unlocked.

[image]

Comment: I do not want to delete the build I just want to unlock it

Comment: Find the release definition that retain the build, and then uncheck the `Retain associated artifacts`, you'll see the build will be unlocked. Check my updated screeshot.

Comment: Thank u so much that was really helpful. I do not want to do that but i know why this is happening now , My question is after the release get deleted after 30 days is the build that has lock on it but not flagged as retain get deleted as well?

Comment: When you delete a release pipeline, delete a release, or when the retention policy deletes a release automatically, the retention policy for the associated build will determine when that build is deleted. Check this documentation for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/retention?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#interaction-between-build-and-release-retention-policies.